# Как вернуть значение из feach?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

У меня есть запрос к серверу, на который приходит ответ в виде массива объектов.
Данные из массива я хочу занести в переменные чтобы потом передать их как свойства компонентам реакт, но у меня не получается. Помогите!

```js
(function getData () {
    fetch(endpoint, myInit)
       .then(res => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
     
    })
  }())
  
 
  
let course = data.map((result) => {
  return (result.courseName)
})
```

Также не могу понять почему если сохранить значение в глобальную переменную то оно сохраняется, но в последствии при обращении к его ячейке выдает UNDEFIND

```js
let data = {};

(function getData () {
    fetch(endpoint, myInit)
       .then(res => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
      data.res = res;
    })
  }())
  
 
console.log(data) // выводит объект
console.log(data.res) // выводит undefind
```

Comment: Ключевое слово "потом", что с латыни на латинский язык переводится как "асинхронно".

Comment: Потому что на момент работы строчки `console.log(data.res)` сервер ещё не успел ответить. Потому что строчка `data.res = res;` сработает потом